# How to document instance of a ES6 class with JSDoc

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsdoc

Defined a class as per [How to document ECMA6 classes with JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715994/how-to-document-ecma6-classes-with-jsdoc) :

```
/**
 * Class representing some action
 */
class someActionClass {}
```

Now how should I define its instance? Could it be as below:

```
/**
* <WHAT GOES HERE?>
*/
someAction = new someActionClass();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable type can be specified with [`@type` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

```
/**
 * @type {someActionClass}
 */
var someAction = new someActionClass();
```